# Springboot:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'showAuthorsView' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, fxml

I found the following error in springboot application. The error part in FXMLController.java is uploaded here. Also uploaded its necessary files. I'am trying to connect java and fxml file. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance

LibraryAutomationApplication.java

```
package com.alphabot.library;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import com.alphabot.library.config.StageManager;
import com.alphabot.library.view.FxmlView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LibraryAutomationApplication extends Application {

    protected ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    protected StageManager stageManager;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = springBootApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        stageManager = springContext.getBean(StageManager.class, stage);
        //stage.setResizable(false);
        //stage.setFullScreen(true);
        showLoginView();
        stage.setMinWidth(1000);
        stage.setMinHeight(650);
    }

    private void showLoginView() throws IOException {
        stageManager.switchScene(FxmlView.MAIN);
    }


    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.close();
    }

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springBootApplicationContext() {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(LibraryAutomationApplication.class);
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().stream().toArray(String[]::new);
        return builder.run(args);
    }
}
```

AppJavaConfig.java

```
package com.alphabot.library.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

import com.alphabot.library.logging.ExceptionWriter;

@Configuration
public class AppJavaConfig {

    @Autowired 
    SpringFXMLLoader springFXMLLoader;

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public ExceptionWriter exceptionWriter() {
        return new ExceptionWriter(new StringWriter());
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundle resourceBundle() {
        return ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle");
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy(value = true)
    public StageManager stageManager(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        return new StageManager(springFXMLLoader, stage);
    }

}
```

SpringFXMLLoader.java

```
package com.alphabot.library.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

@Component
public class SpringFXMLLoader {

    private final ResourceBundle resourceBundle;
    private final ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    public SpringFXMLLoader(ApplicationContext context, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        this.resourceBundle = resourceBundle;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Parent load(String fxmlPath) throws IOException {      
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
        loader.setResources(resourceBundle);
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
        return loader.load();
    }


}
```

StageManager.java

```
package com.alphabot.library.config;


import static org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger;

import java.util.Objects;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.alphabot.library.view.FxmlView;
import com.alphabot.library.config.StageManager;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageManager {

    private static final Logger LOG = getLogger(StageManager.class);
    private SpringFXMLLoader springFXMLLoader;
    private final Stage primaryStage;

    public StageManager(SpringFXMLLoader springFXMLLoader, Stage stage) {
        this.springFXMLLoader = springFXMLLoader;
        this.primaryStage = stage;
    }

    @Autowired
    public Node switchScene(final FxmlView view) {
        Parent viewRootNodeHierarchy = loadViewNodeHierarchy(view.getFxmlFile());
        show(viewRootNodeHierarchy, view.getTitle());
        return viewRootNodeHierarchy;
    }

    private void show(final Parent rootnode, String title) {
        Scene scene = prepareScene(rootnode);

        primaryStage.setTitle(title);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

        try {
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logAndExit ("Unable to show scene for title" + title,  exception);
        }

    }
    private Scene prepareScene(Parent rootnode){
        Scene scene = primaryStage.getScene();

        if (scene == null) {
            scene = new Scene(rootnode);
        }
        scene.setRoot(rootnode);
        return scene;
    }

    private Parent loadViewNodeHierarchy(String fxmlFilePath) {
        Parent rootNode = null;
        try {
            rootNode = springFXMLLoader.load(fxmlFilePath);
            Objects.requireNonNull(rootNode, "A Root FXML node must not be null");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logAndExit("Unable to load FXML view" + fxmlFilePath, exception);
        }
        return rootNode;
    }

    private void logAndExit(String errorMsg, Exception exception) {
        LOG.error(errorMsg, exception, exception.getCause());
        Platform.exit();
    }

}
```

FXMLController.java

```
    package com.alphabot.library.controller;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import com.alphabot.library.config.StageManager;
    import com.alphabot.library.view.FxmlView;
    import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;

    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    @Component
    public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

        protected StageManager stageManager;
        protected ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

        @FXML
        private StackPane mainPane;
        @FXML
        private JFXButton btnHome;
        @FXML
        private JFXButton btnAuthors;
        @FXML
        private JFXButton btnBooks;
        @FXML
        private JFXButton btnJournals;
        @FXML
        private JFXButton btnIssueReturn;

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

            try {
                mainPane.getChildren().clear();
                mainPane.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/HomePanel.fxml")));

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        @FXML
        private void homeOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
            Stage stage = (Stage) btnHome.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setTitle("Library Management- Home");
            try {
                mainPane.getChildren().clear();
                mainPane.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/HomePanel.fxml")));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        @FXML
        private void authorsOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            mainPane.getChildren().clear();
            mainPane.getChildren().add(showAuthorsView());
        }

        @Bean
        private Node showAuthorsView() throws IOException {
            stageManager = springContext.getBean(StageManager.class, mainPane);
            return stageManager.switchScene(FxmlView.AUTHORS);
        }

        @FXML
        private void booksOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
           // Stage stage = (Stage) btnBooks.getScene().getWindow();
           // stage.setTitle("Library Management- Books");
            try {
                mainPane.getChildren().clear();
                mainPane.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/BooksPanel.fxml")));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        @FXML
        private void journalsOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
            Stage stage = (Stage) btnJournals.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setTitle("Library Management- Journals");
            try {
                mainPane.getChildren().clear();
                mainPane.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/JournalsPanel.fxml")));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        @FXML
        private void issueReturnOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
            Stage stage = (Stage) btnIssueReturn.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setTitle("Library Management- Issue or Return");
            try {
                mainPane.getChildren().clear();
                mainPane.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/IssueReturnPanel.fxml")));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }


    }

ExceptionWriter.java

package com.alphabot.library.logging;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class ExceptionWriter extends PrintWriter {
    public ExceptionWriter(Writer writer) {
        super(writer);
    }

    private String wrapAroundWithNewlines(String stringWithoutNewlines) {
        return ("\n" + stringWithoutNewlines + "\n");
    }

    public String getExceptionAsString(Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace(this);

        String exception = super.out.toString();

        return (wrapAroundWithNewlines(exception));
    }

}
```

FxmlView.java

```
package com.alphabot.library.view;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public enum FxmlView {

    LOGIN {
        @Override
        public String getTitle() {
            return getStringFromResourceBundle("login.title");
        }

        @Override
        public String getFxmlFile() {
            return "/fxml/Login.fxml";
        }
    },

    MAIN {
        @Override
        public String getTitle() {
            return getStringFromResourceBundle("login.title");
        }

        @Override
        public String getFxmlFile() {
            return "/fxml/MainPanel.fxml";
        }
    },

    AUTHORS {
        @Override
        public String getTitle() {
            return getStringFromResourceBundle("login.title");
        }

        @Override
        public String getFxmlFile() {
            return "/fxml/AuthorsPanel.fxml";
        }
    },

    FPASS {
        @Override
        public String getTitle() {
            return getStringFromResourceBundle("forgotPassword.title");
        }

        @Override
        public String getFxmlFile() {
            return "/fxml/ForgotPassword.fxml";
        }
    };

    public abstract String getTitle();
    public abstract String getFxmlFile();

    String getStringFromResourceBundle(String key){
        return ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle").getString(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the logs?

Comment: Jonathan Johx- Thank you for your interest to solve the issue. Actually I got the solution. The issue because of Annotation miss matching. Thank you very much

Comment: you're welcome. If you have the solution. it'd be nice that you post it :) kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I changed FXMLController.java like this

```
package com.alphabot.library.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.alphabot.library.config.StageManager;
import com.alphabot.library.view.*;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

@Component
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private StackPane mainPane;

    protected Node home, authors, books, journals, issue_return;

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private StageManager stageManager;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            mainPane.getChildren().clear();
            mainPane.getChildren().add(stageManager.switchScene(FxmlView.HOME));

            home = stageManager.switchScene(FxmlView.HOME);
            authors = stageManager.switchScene(FxmlView.AUTHORS);
            books = stageManager.switchScene(FxmlView.BOOKS);
            journals = stageManager.switchScene(FxmlView.JOURNALS);
            issue_return = stageManager.switchScene(FxmlView.ISSUE_RETURN);
    }

    @FXML
    private void homeOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            mainPane.getChildren().clear();
            mainPane.getChildren().add(home);
    }

    @FXML
    private void authorsOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            mainPane.getChildren().clear();
            mainPane.getChildren().add(authors);
    }

    @FXML
    private void booksOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            mainPane.getChildren().clear();
            mainPane.getChildren().add(books);
    }

    @FXML
    private void journalsOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            mainPane.getChildren().clear();
            mainPane.getChildren().add(journals);
    }

    @FXML
    private void issueReturnOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            mainPane.getChildren().clear();
            mainPane.getChildren().add(issue_return);
    }

}
```